# How can this C# method be shortened?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have two List objects, and each Person has an index ranking for which one should go first in a line. Both lists are sorted from low to high, respectively. Currently, I don't have the opportunity to create two sample lists to test this myself, and I don't want to stop coding so I thought I'd ask here hopefully for a relatively quick response.

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
    {
        while(training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
        {
            if(training.Count == 0)
            {
                Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
            }
            else if(testing.Count == 0)
            {
                Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
            }
            else if(training[0].Index < testing[0].Index)
            {
                Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
            }
            else
            {
                Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
            }
        }
    }

public static void GrabFromList(List<Person> output, List<Person> target)
    {
        output.Add(target.First());
        target.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

The conditional checks are pretty ugly. Is it safe to combine my statements like this,

```
if(training.Count == 0 || testing[0] < training[0]) 
{
    Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
}
```

or will this throw an error as it's possible training[0] is null? Does C# exit the conditional check if the first condition is already True in an || comparison?

Comment: *"I don't have the opportunity to create two sample lists to test this myself, and I don't want to stop coding"*: I appreciate the honesty, but this is exactly what is expected from you before asking a question on StackOverflow... to put in a little effort yourself first.

Comment: why if and else if both contain same condition can you please explain.

Comment: @PankajGupta - They don't - one is `training` and the other is `testing`.

Comment: *"I don't have the opportunity to create two sample lists to test this myself, and I don't want to stop coding"* That won't take you far... You should be responsible for your code and test it sufficiently. Otherwise you are just hoping you are lucky!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `c#` ignores subsequent conditions if first statement results as `true` in `||` operation.

So, in your below condition if `training.Count == 0` check results true, it will not do `testing[0] < training[0]` check

```
if(training.Count == 0 || testing[0] < training[0]) 
{
    Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
}
```

Comment: Unless the < operator is overloaded for the Person type, this code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you must always check this `null`. It will stop evaluating, if first condition is `true`, but what if not?

As for logic, I think you can do `output.AddRange(training); output.AddRange(testing)`. Since, looking just at `while(training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)` i see that both lists are just inserted in third.

If there are some sorting conditions applied to resulting list, verbalize them and I will be able to give you code snippet to sort them. Logic in your conditions seems broken and I don't what to second guess, what do you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the different options and this is how I could simplify the logic:

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
{
    while (training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
    {
        if (training.Count > 0 && (testing.Count == 0 ^ training[0].Index < testing[0].Index))
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
        }
        else
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
        }
    }
}
```

Inline if to reduce it even more at the expense of legibility:

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
{
    while (training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
        Controller.GrabFromList(output, training.Count > 0 && (testing.Count == 0 ^ training[0].Index < testing[0].Index) ? training : testing);
}
```

Or check for the opposite:

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
{
    while (training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
    {
        if (training.Count == 0 || (testing.Count > 0 && training[0].Index >= testing[0].Index))
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
        }
        else
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, inline if to reduce it even more at the expense of legibility:

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
{
    while (training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
        Controller.GrabFromList(output, training.Count == 0 || (testing.Count > 0 && training[0].Index >= testing[0].Index) ? testing : training);
}
```

I didn't try the code, it may even not compile, I leave that up to you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider readability as well as efficiency.  The other answers are incomplete and are a little bit difficult to read.  Here is your code modified to include all of the required checks:

```
public void ConsolidateLists()
{
    while(training.Count > 0 || testing.Count > 0)
    {
        if(training.Count == 0 || training[0] == null)
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
        }
        else if(testing.Count == 0 || testing[0] == null)
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
        }
        else if(training[0].Index < testing[0].Index)
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, training);
        }
        else
        {
            Controller.GrabFromList(output, testing);
        }
    }
}

public static void GrabFromList(List<Person> output, List<Person> target)
{
    if (target[0] != null)
        output.Add(target[0]);
    target.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

I check for null in the GrabFromList method because I'm guessing you don't want to add the null values to your output.  I also removed the First() extension method in favor of the indexer.  First() would instantiate an enumerator, move to the first item, them return that item.  Then it would have to be eventually destroyed.  The indexer is already there, so it saves CPU time and memory.  If you want the code to be more compact vertically you could remove the curly braces.